# Locking Composite Console in Azure Production

Tags: azure, c1-cms

I have moved our corporate site to Azure.
I have set up the staging site on Azure to and installed til Azure Publisher Elastic package to public to the production site which is also hosted on Azure. Everything works like a charm.

However I would like to lock down the Composite console on the Production site so our editors won't fire up the production console by mistake. E.I. I only want our editor to edit content in the staging site. What is best practice to prevent our editors from firing up the production console?

Comment: Adding the line: <Remapping requestPath="/composite" requestHost="yourproductiondomain.dk" requestPathStartsWith="true" requestHostEndsWith="true" rewritePath="/composite/top.aspx" rewriteHost="yourstagingdomain.dk"  />  Using the RequestUrlRemappings.Xml solved it.

Comment: PLEASE NOTICE!!!! requestHostEndWith must be false!!

Answer (score 0):

what version of Composite are you running?

In 4.0 there is a xml file that you can close access with, `/App_Data/Composite/Configuration/C1ConsoleAccesss.xml`.

In the deployment folder on Azure Storage, /DeploymentFolder/Configuration/Websites.xml - depending on enableBlobWriteBacks is true or false, it should also lock down the site c1 console access.

If set to true (site is writing its data back to the storage account) its open. 
If its set to false c1 console is closed : (the setting you want if you are using Azure Publisher, such live sites are not sending data back to the storage account, and when you publish from your staging site it sends the files to the storage account and when its done, the production site will download all changed files).